# Accessor and mutator c++ method in class arrray [3][3]

Tags: c++

I am a beginner programmer, I have a problem with the task. I have to use method set(), get() to initialize elements of matrix [3][3], but **I have to make universal method for all elements.**

Please help!

```
//mat3.hpp

class mat3 {

public:

    mat3(); //Default constructor, double loop initialize 0.0

    mat3(float v11, float v12, float v13,
        float v21, float v22, float v23,
        float v31, float v32, float v33);//Constructor with arguments

    void print(); //Method printing matrix

private:

    float data[3][3];

};
```

Comment: What are you finding difficult about the task? What is it you don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getter/setter methods:

```
class mat3
{
    // ...

    void setElement(const unsigned row, const unsigned col, const float value) 
    {
        data[row][col] = value;
    }

    float getElement(const unsigned row, const unsigned col) const
    {
        return data[row][col];
    }

}
```

It would be good to check the row and column indexes passed into the getter/setter functions are within bounds, you can do this with an [assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert).

Comment: I would be good to mention that `std::assert` is only active when you're compiling without `NDEBUG` so In production (where `NDEBUG` is normally used) `std::assert` won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your instructor whether or not you are allowed to go trans-universal and combine the setter and getter:

```
float & operator(int row, int column) 
{ 
    return data[row][column]; 
}
```

The `()` operator allows you to use the object like a function. The two parameters provide the coordinates for the array look up. The funtion returns a reference to the requested array element so you can set it or get it to your heart's content.

Usage

```
float x = mymat(1,2);
```

as a getter or

```
mymat(1,2) = 3.14;
```

as a setter. For debugging purposes you may want to add tests to ensure `row` and `column` are not out of range. You may also want to return a `const` version

```
float operator(int row, int column) const
{ 
    return data[row][column]; 
}
```

for use with read-only objects. This doesn't work as a setter, obviously.

If you can't use this approach, you can still take the basic idea and pass in the coordinates you want to get or set as parameters.